# GCP - switching to service account method

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

Following Coursera [Architecting with Google Kubernetes Engine](https://www.coursera.org/learn/foundations-google-kubernetes-engine-gke/lecture/1pxSX/lab-solution) for switching to Service Account.

It says create and download a key file and authenticate using the key. Is this the common way in GCP? There will be many keys created by developers and downloaded to many laptops or servers scattering the keys in many places, which seems to be not secure manner.

[image]

Comment: What is your goal here? Service accounts are mainly intended to be used by applications, while gcloud/cloud shell is used by users. You can impersonate a service account for debugging purposes the way you provided, or by using short lived keys, or using the impersonation function in gcloud. But normally you just use cloud shell as your user account, not as a SA.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question, yes. The service accounts are the common way to authenticate in GCP.

There are two different service account types, and the recommendation is to use the second one:

- **User Managed Service Accounts:** to authenticate you will then need a “password” that comes in the form of Service Account Key (json file), and if you leak the service account key, the service account can be considered compromised.

  Using keys implies that you are in charge of their lifecycle and security, and it’s a lot to ask because:

  1. You need a robust system for secrets distribution.
  2. You need to implement a key rotation policy.
  3. You need to implement safeguards to prevent key leaks.
- **Google Managed Service Account:** Google Managed Service Accounts, are SAs for which you don’t need to generate keys and your applications can just assume their identity. No keys are involved: the VM will continuously request short lived authorization tokens from the metadata service.

[Documentation](https://cloudberry.engineering/article/google-cloud-service-accounts-security-best-practices/)

Answer (score 1):

NO, no and no, don't use service account key file. As you smell it, you are right, it's a terrible thing for the security.

Today, there are several way to prevent the service account key usage, even if, in some corner case, you need them.

I have wrote bunch of articles on that topics:

- the [limits](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c)
- the [service account credential API](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115)
- and a [fight against a Google dev advocate and one of his article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-oauth-credential-going-deeper-the-hard-way-f403cf3edf9d)

Because YES, even Google tutorials, courses, documentation (...) promote that bad practice for years and continue. It was my nightmare in my previous company, and I increased my knowledge and skill to prevent key usage and find workarounds. Let me know your use case, I will try to help your the most